# android restore transactions keeps shutting down app after exit

Tags: android, transactions, restore, in-app-billing

I use the code according to the dungeons sample. Everything works fine except one thing. The thing is restoring transactions. When I call restore transaction the same way as in the sample, everything seems fine. It looks like he reas beetwith no errors generated. But then I wait, 3 to 10 minutes (which I ik is enough to get eosrom google server). but no response comes....I dot kof I do somethinng way ... ??

This is my code used for restore trans...

```
mBillingService.restoreTransactions(); 

public boolean restoreTransactions() {
    return new RestoreTransactions().runRequest();
}
class RestoreTransactions extends BillingRequest {
    long mNonce;

    public RestoreTransactions() {
        // This object is never created as a side effect of starting this
        // service so we pass -1 as the startId to indicate that we should
        // not stop this service after executing this request.
        super(-1);
    }

    @Override
    protected long run() throws RemoteException {
        mNonce = Security.generateNonce();

        Log.d("running", "running restore request");
        Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS");
        request.putLong(Consts.BILLING_REQUEST_NONCE, mNonce);
        Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);
        logResponseCode("restoreTransactions", response);
        return response.getLong(Consts.BILLING_RESPONSE_REQUEST_ID,
                Consts.BILLING_RESPONSE_INVALID_REQUEST_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRemoteException(RemoteException e) {
        super.onRemoteException(e);
        Security.removeNonce(mNonce);
    }

    @Override
    protected void responseCodeReceived(ResponseCode responseCode) {
        ResponseHandler.responseCodeReceived(BillingService.this, this, responseCode);
    }
}
```

Which is in fact the same as the dungeons sample. But I got no response for this snippet. But if I want to buy an item there is no problem. 
So does anyone know how to solve this? I am getting responses for buying but no responses for restoring....

And after all if I finish my intent and finish my app, then the following error occurs. It seems like the response comes after the end of the app. It doesn't come during run but after finishing all intents.

And another weird thing is that on destroy I am unbinding the service and context for billing. So in fact, should this even be called? I think no ?

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Log cat error below.

```
12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start        service .BillingService@40da8db0 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2749)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:139)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at .BillingService.handleCommand(BillingService.java:431)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at .BillingService.onStart(BillingService.java:421)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:438)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    12-24 01:33:06.212: E/AndroidRuntime(27721):    ... 10 more
```